# nltk chunker to extract key information from a business processing request

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk, chunking

I am trying to collect various key information from the below text using NLTK chunking.

I need the old and new form numbers, effective date, list of states and list of products in separate lists.

I used the below code :

```
script = 'please replace the forms CA1235 and CB3456 effective from 12/26/2018 with CA5467 for the state of Alabama, California and North Carolina for CAB and WCP products.'

# POS Tagging method
scrtagged = pos_tag(word_tokenize(script, language='english'))
print('Parts of speech tagging:',scrtagged)

screntities = nltk.chunk.ne_chunk(scrtagged)
print('Entities extracted:', screntities)

pattern = """ 
VBD:{<VBD>} 
STATE:{<GPE>}
PRODUCT: r'\D{3}'
FORM:{<IN>?<JJ>?<ORGANIZATION>+|<JJ>?<NN>+<ORGANIZATION>}
EFFDATE1: r'\d+\/*\-*\d+\/*\-*\d{2,4}'
EFFDATE:{<IN><CD>|<IN><JJ>}
"""

NPChunker = nltk.RegexpParser(pattern) 
result = NPChunker.parse(list(screntities))

result.pprint()
```

The output I am getting is as below:

```
(S
  please/VB
  replace/VB
  the/DT
  forms/NNS
  (FORM (ORGANIZATION CA1235/NNP))
  and/CC
  (FORM (ORGANIZATION CB3456/NNP))
  effective/JJ
  (EFFDATE from/IN 12/26/2018/CD)
  (FORM with/IN (ORGANIZATION CA5467/NNP))
  for/IN
  the/DT
  state/NN
  of/IN
  (STATE (GPE Alabama/NNP))
  ,/,
  (STATE (GPE California/NNP))
  and/CC
  (FORM (ORGANIZATION Illinois/NNP))
  (FORM for/IN (ORGANIZATION CAB/NNP))
  and/CC
  (FORM (ORGANIZATION WCP/NNP))
  products/NNS
  ./.)
```

As you can see there are multiple issue. Illinois is not recognised as GPE by the nltk chunker. 
EFFDATE 1 pattern is not recognised.
PRODUCT pattern is not working.

I need capability to identify the new form and old forms list distinctly. Don't know how to do that.

You may know from above that i am beginner and have a complex task on hand. My objective is to trigger a workflow in a 3rd party business software using the values from free form English request emails. 
Please help me identify the issues and corrected usage of nltk chunker.

Comment: What's the expected output exactly?

Comment: I need a list of states, list of products, list of new form name, old form names and effective date. As given below:

States: Alabama, California, Illinois
Products: CAB, WCP
Old Forms: CA1235, CB3456
New Form: CA5467
Effective Date: 12/26/2018 (always in mm/dd/yyyy)

Comment: Can you update your question to include that information?